# Python Writing huge string in text file with a new line character every 240 characters

Tags: python, html, mammoth

I need to convert a word document into html code and then save it into a .txt file with lines of no longer than 100 characters (there's a process later on that won't pick up more than 255 characters if they're not in separate lines).

So far, I've successfully (though a better solution is welcome) managed to convert the .docx file into html and deploy that variable into a .txt file. However, I'm not able to figure out how to separate the lines. Is there any integrated function which could achieve this?

```
import mammoth

with open(r'C:\Users\uXXXXXX\Downloads\Test_Script.docx', "rb") as docx_file:
    result = mammoth.convert_to_html(docx_file)
    html = result.value # The generated HTML
    messages = result.messages # Any messages, such as warnings during conversion
    
with open(r'C:\Users\uXXXXXX\Downloads\Output.txt', 'w') as text_file:
    text_file.write(html)
```

Comment: It's not stated, but I suspect you don't want newlines in the middle of words, or tags right?

Comment: Would inserting a newline every 100 characters into `html` work for you?

Comment: Sorry, not required. Just inserting a newline every 100 characters would work, yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, you can just do

```
html = "..."
i = 100
while i < len(html):
    html = html[:i] + "\n" + html[i:]
    i += 101
```

Comment: Thanks. I may need an additional question for this, but, is it possible to maintain the word color formatting when converting the word document to html?

Comment: @JaviTorre Possibly. Docx is basically html with spice, so using a proper library, yes. However, the docx format is proprietary, so there is little to no documentation on the subject. You might want to ask an additional question for this. I just know how to insert characters into strings in python :D